# Refering Workbooks Using a Variable

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm using a workbook which will help, based on the information it contains, to move more information into different workbooks. To be more clear:

This is the code:

```
Sub FEID01()

Dim D, M, A As Variant

D = Workbooks("FE-ID-01").Sheets("FE-ID-01").Range("C2")
M = Workbooks("FE-ID-01").Sheets("FE-ID-01").Range("D2")
A = Workbooks("FE-ID-01").Sheets("FE-ID-01").Range("E2")

Workbooks("FE-ID-01").Activate
Workbooks("FE-ID-01").Sheets("FE-ID-01").Range("C2:E2").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks(A).Activate
Workbooks(A).Sheets(M).Range("C2").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The variables D, M, and A collect the information from a specific cell, then based on the information of it, I'm copying and pasting a range of cells.

I'm using the information in variable A to choose the workbook where the information will be transferred, however its not working. Is there a way to do this, so when the value of A changes, the information will be redirected to a different workbook?

I hope I made myself clear enough.

Comment: So A has the name of an open Workbook?

Comment: STOP!!!! Watch this video:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset) - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&t=3123s&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: I can't understand how even `Workbooks("FE-ID-01")` works, unless you have created an excel file without an extension (which is possible, but definitely not a good idea).

Comment: Fun fact: `Dim D, M, A As Variant` declares `D` and `M` as *implicit* `Variant` variables, and `A` as an *explicit* `Variant`. If you need them to be strings, declare them all `As String`.

Comment: @YowE3K - That would work if the file hasn't been saved yet.  ;-)

Comment: @Comintern - I didn't know you could assign a name to a workbook, other than by saving it.

Comment: @YowE3K - Good point.

Comment: Wouldn't `Workbooks("FE-ID-01")` work fine if the file is already open? From my understanding you are just referencing the Workbook from the Workbooks collection using its file name.

Comment: @nbayly just tested it, nope - throws *index out of range*.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your workbook and worksheets explicitly in a variable. This is helpful as well as it it is referenced multiple times in your code.

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim rngCopy as Range
Dim rngPaste as Range

Set wb = Application.Workbooks("FE-ID-01.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("FE-ID-01.xlsm")
Set rngCopy = ws.Range("C2:E2")
Set rngPaste = ws.Range("C2:E2")
wb.Activate
```

Your sample data is confusing though as your are copying and pasting from and to the same sheet/range so please correct properly before putting to use. Regards,